# CSS relative path locally - not rendering (file://)

Tags: html, css

I am losing my mind.

Folder structure:

```
spend
  css
   - app.css
  js
   - app.js
  index.html
```

In the head of the HTML file:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
```

app.css

```
//= Main App CSS File
//----------------------

.header {
    color: red;
}
```

I browse to:  file:///Users/john/Projects/spend/index.html

No CSS rendered. (i.e.  the header class text should be red)

What the heck is Chrome (or me) doing!?

Comment: I'm assuming `header` is indeed a `class`, and not an `id`, in the html!

Comment: Does the CSS load when you use the full file path? What about when you have them in the same folder and just use `href="app.css"`?

Comment: @flowstoneknight - doesn't load anywhere I put it. I've tried what you've suggested.

Comment: Are there other CSS rules that might overwrite it, such as `p`, `span`, or `h1`?

Comment: And yes, I can access the file going right to the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this from your css file please (its wrong and is breaking your otherwise fine formatting)

//= Main App CSS File
//----------------------

Comment: O M G. I was using SASS commenting... 
Thank you for helping me see the light.